# Flutter компиляция под iOS

Tags: flutter

Необходимо свободно компилировать под iOS приложения написанные на Flutter.
Какое устройство может минимально подойти, чтобы его хватило года на два еще?
Какие могут встретиться "подводные камни"?
Про онлайн сервисы знаю, интересно узнать во сколько это будет обходиться, если купить для этих целей устройство от Apple.